How to denote domain and range of a function that substitutes a given interval?
I neeed to denote the range and domain of a function that subsitutes a given interval with a diffirent interval.
For example: $f ([x,y]) = [x, x + \frac{y-x}{2}]$
My thoughts were $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$, however $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ is reserved for mapping numbers to numbers rather then interval. I thought something like $f: [0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$ could work, but it seems it will overcomplicate defining the function.
I would appriciate if someone could introduce me to a neat notation for defining interval subsitutions.

How about something like:
We write $I_c$ to denote the set of closed intervals $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \leq b$.
Consider a function $f:I_c \rightarrow I_c$ defined by (etc).
The main goal of this type of setup is defining cumbersome notation with parsimonious notation, as in the case of $I_c$ above, so that it can be written about more efficiently later on.
